# MATLAB: Plotting 1D Conditional Distributions with kdensity stacked in a 3D figure

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a T x 2 Matrix, where in the second column I have some daily financial returns and in the first column I have an indicator, which can assume integer values in the interval [1, 9].

I want to extract 9 different conditional distributions of my returns, conditioned on the values assumed by the indicator. At this point, I want to plot the conditional densities through a Gaussian smoothing with the function 'ksdensity' and plot them in the same 3D plot. The final output should be similar to this one: [Image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F38747732%2Fmultiple-1d-plots-in-a-3d-plot&psig=AOvVaw2jN2douoGr7OGA1NNLskAg&ust=1635186304829000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCKD2m-7V4_MCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)

I tried to reach this result by adapting the answer I found at this thread: [Function](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/340919-multiple-2d-plot-in-1-3d-plot).
Now suppose that x = axis of returns, y = axis of indicator possible values, z = smoothed conditional densities.

My problem is that, while in the example the meshgrid required for all the values of y have the same values of x by construction, I have different values of x (the returns) because of the conditioning.

Answer (score 0):

First split your returns data into 9 vectors, according to the indicator variable. You can use [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) for that. Then run [ksdensity](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html) on each vector separately. Then plot those outputs.